# Is there a way to list all invocations and hardcoded string parameters of a method from a .Net assembly?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, reflection, assemblies

For example, assume that in my assembly, in Namespace A, Class B, there is an instance method with the following signature:

```
void Test(string someString, int someOtherParm, string someOtherString );
```

This method is called multiple times, from multiple places in the assembly.
I would like to be able build a list of all invocations of this method and the value of the someString/someOtherString (assuming they are hardcoded).

In other words, I like to extract a list of calls like the example one below, if they happen in the assembly somewhere:

```
Test("some text", 8, "some other text");
```

Thanks in advance,
R.

Comment: did you solve this? fancy posting a solution?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [Cecil](http://www.mono-project.com/Cecil) library, which is a very powerful IL inspection and modification API.  You will want to create a "method visitor" that will scan for call instructions and attempt to locate constant strings loaded onto the stack.